# One Word Alternative for "Increase Productivity"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

Is there a single English word (preferably a verb) which can replace the phrase "increase productivity" or "increase your productivity"?

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by an example sentence that includes some context.

Answer (score 1):

Check the synonyms of augment, to find words like "grow", "inflate", and "boost" - and more which will be helpful.

I'd also recommend "goose" and "burgeoning".

Answer (score 0):

In ascending order of ridiculousness and literary opacity, here are some suggestions:

We need a [hike](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hike) (def 5).

We need a [step-up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/step-up).

We need a [goose](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/goose) (def 6), or we need to goose-up production.

We need some [burgeoning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/burgeoning) here.

We need some [waxing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wax) (a pun which alludes simultaneously to waxing as a transitive verb - to wax the competition, and an intransitive verb as in the waxing and waning of the moon). Obviously most people will think of body hair removal, but I can't help it if the English language allows these connections to be made, now, can I?

Comment: Don't you think those terms are all synonyms for "increase", not alternatives to "increase productivity"?

Comment: Most if not all constructions would be metaphorical. The term 'productivity' would easily be inferred from context.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the reason melvynkim Asked was that he didn't have one of your crystal balls. If the term 'productivity' would easily be inferred from context, would would be the point of the Question?

Answer (score 0):

We need a hike IN productivity.

We need to step up productivity (a step-up in productivity).

"Goose" is a problematic word because it calls to mind pinching someone's bottom: unintended connotative association.

Saying that "we need some waxing" sounds sort of ridiculous for anyone who reads books. It's the wrong connotation entirely. These words aren't used this way.

Comment: Answers are expected to directly address the question. If you have comments on other answers these should be made by using the comments option under the answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/412802)